# Resize the size of following div for responsive design

Tags: html, css

How can I re-size the following `<div>` for responsive design while keeping exact ratio?

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p class="ls-l" data-ls="offsetxin:30; delayin:1000; skewxin:-40; offsetxout:-30; durationout:1000; skewxout:-40;">
      <span class="slide-span textStyle">
          <strong class="slide2-header bigBlueHeader">Louez votre matériel médical en ligne</strong>
          <br><br>
          LMAD est la première solution nationale de <strong>location de matériel médical</strong>
          <br> 
          en ligne pour le domicile. Une livraison garantie du jour au lendemain<br> 
          <strong>sur toute la France</strong> et sans avance de frais.
      </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.textStyle {
    color:#454545; 
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:300; 
    font-size:18px; 
    text-align: center; 
    line-height:22px; 
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:13px 20px 13px 30px;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.bigBlueHeader {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size:32px;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#4195cd;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bababa;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

And last but not least here is a **[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kjw7dh1j/)** of what I have now.

Comment: Which element you are referring to? There's no `div` in the code. Plus, there is no information on the size, nor the sizing rules for any element. Lastly, it seems like you're using a plugin which takes data from the `data-ls`tag to change the `p` tag's behavior.

Comment: Sorry the whole element will be in a div . I missed it . I want to size will be 786 , 360 , 1024

Comment: Can you re-paste the code including the div? and any styles on it? Are you using bootstrap? If so, what version? Also, if that div will be in another div, that will affect the output as well. We need a lot more information.

Comment: i am not using bootstrap

Comment: In my honest opinion, your best bet is going to be implementing **boostrap**, **http://responsejs.com** or something like that, and then using their grid template **http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/** This way you don't have to think about math but put in an already existing class to the div and bootstrap does the work. It will save you HOURS.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a fiddle, and added a background of grey so you could see the div changing size: http://jsfiddle.net/revn7LLt/1/

This uses CSS a media query.  Width of at least 360px will size the div to 360px wide and so forth up to 1000px.

CSS:

```
div {

    background: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 360px)  {
    div {
        width: 360px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    div {
        width: 768px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    div {
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Comment: what will be the solution for max-width :360 , max-width :768px . I can't figure out it .

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking.  If you look at the fiddle, you can resize the four quadrants.  Resize the width of the  lower-right quadrant and you can see the div resize.  For widths of at least 1000px the div width is 1000, for widths of at least 768px (but less than 1000px) the width is 768.  The 360 one is somewhat superfluous.  If you change this to max, it would resize the element before the screen is big enough to accept it.